# Perl to PHP function conversion - help needed

Tags: php, perl

I have a subroutine/function in Perl like this:

```
sub numToStr {
   my ($ipnum) = @_;
   my $z = $ipnum % 256;
   $ipnum >>= 8;
   my $y = $ipnum % 256;
   $ipnum >>= 8;
   my $x = $ipnum % 256;
   $ipnum >>= 8;
   my $w = $ipnum % 256;

   return "$w.$x.$y.$z";
}
```

any ideas how to make it into PHP alternative ?

many thanks,
cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function numToStr($ipnum)
{
   $z = $ipnum % 256;
   $ipnum >>= 8;
   $y = $ipnum % 256;
   $ipnum >>= 8;
   $x = $ipnum % 256;
   $ipnum >>= 8;
   $w = $ipnum % 256;

   return "$w.$x.$y.$z";
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`long2ip()`](http://php.net/long2ip) function.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder whether http://php.net/long2ip is what you want.